# Problems with Chrome, Skype and Discord - possible MITM attack?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, virus, virus-removal

Two days ago everything was working just fine, but then I got this error in Google Chrome:

> Your connection is not private. www.youtube.com might attempt to steal your personal information.

At the same time Discord went completely grey, Skype was just rolling, couldn't connect.

I checked Internet Explorer and it was working perfectly. I thought it was just a issue with Chrome, so I cleaned up Chrome, tested again, still the same issue. I tried cleaning it using CCleaner, still the same issue. I did a powerfull unistall using IOBit uninstaller. Reinstalled, still not working.

Then Norton started blocking Reddit, Youtube and Facebook in Internet Explorer.

> www.youtube.com is dangerous

I thought I had a virus so I did a virus scan in Norton, nothing, Avira, still nothing, tried using Malwarebytes, still nothing, tried using AdwCleaner, didn't find anything.

Then I booted up in Safemode, still the same issue. I did a DNS flush. I ran a scan in Wireshark and saw ARP requests. I thought someone was attempting a man in the middle attack. But it only affected one computer. I figured out these requests came from my internet Adapter.

Now I'm getting certificate warnings and it is not like scetchy ones, they are the legit websites. It is like someone is targeting this one computer.

I found [this link](http://thehackernews.com/2017/03/google-invalidate-symantec-certs.html). But how could this effect skype, discord and steam?

UPDATE:
I fully reset my computer, wiped out everything, reformated my harddrive. My computer started working for three days, then it won't boot, I have to do a system refresh for it to work again, this happens every third to fourth day. I have done it 23 times now. I taken it to the store to get it checked, they say they can't find anything.

Comment: a) Check your computer date/time.
b) Check chrome extensions and disable them
c) Try to reset chrome to factory (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en)
d) reinstall chrome completely
e) if nothing works, backup your data and reinstall pc

Comment: It certainly does sound like somebody is installing malware... It's you. You are installing dangerous software. You have Norton installed. Your machine is no longer secure, you cannot rely on it's security any more.

Comment: Hi, I checked my date and time, it is correct, I have done a complete reinstall, I will try a refresh on my PC, because it also affects Skype, Discord and Steam aswell

Comment: I don't install much programs, I only have games, editing software, spotify and Visual studio installed.

Comment: Do you have Norton installed?

Comment: Not anymore, Now im using Malwarebytes

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your problem doesn't come from your machine but, most likely, some other component in your network. The prime suspect would be your router. From your description, it olooks very similar to what would happen if your router's [DNS configuration has been changed](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/threat-insight/post/home-routers-under-attack-malvertising-windows-android-devices) (at the very least).

Answer (score 1):

Something ad-ware-like is infesting your system.

Make a clean sweep with Super Anti Spyware, Malwarebytes and Hitman Pro in this order. Some of them are trial versions, but you only need to use them once.

Comment: I tried both, no difference

Comment: If you suspect malware the real answer is to reinstall from scratch. Please don't suggest using antimalware products after the fact as they can give the user a false sense of security without actually removing the malware.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your PC hit by an unknown zero day exploited that crafted the message that looks like Google chrome error message, otherwise, you can perform some cleanup as stated [in this Quara Q&A](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-Your-connections-isn%E2%80%99t-private-problem-when-opening-with-the-Google-Chrome-browser) .

Otherwise, it is rather inconclusive diagnostic.  A rogue chrome extension can cause it; there is possible of adware infested that hijack the connection; corrupted Chrome cache, configuration file; a driver updates; compromised IoT (your router).